# Computing the n-dimensional integral of of guassian curve

Tags: probability

Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ be  $n$ instantiations of  random variable $X$ having the cdf $F(x)$  and  pdf $f(x)$,taking values in the interval $ (a,b) $.Is the expresion correct :
$$ P(x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \dots\leq x_n)=\int_{x_n=a}^b\quad \int_{x_{n-1}=a}^{x_n}\dots \int_{x_1=a}^{x_2} \prod_{i=0}^nf(x_i) dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_n  $$.
How do we compute the above integral for some given $f(x)$.In particular if $X$ is normally distributed so that
$$ f(x_i)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x_i^2/2},i=1,2,3,, \dots,n ,$$
how do we evaluate or find the asymptotic value of the above integral when,say, .Thanks for any help/hints/responces in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming continuous random variables, this integral will evaluate to $1/n!$ regardless of distribution, because what you ask for is one of the n possible permutations of a random sample.

Comment: that is really  elegant.Could  you ,however,just give a hint or sketch about how to elavuate this integral  numerically to corroborate the claim experimentally as well?

Comment: Better, you can do simulations. Multi-dimensional integral estimation can be time consuming, but simply you can try grid estimation, e.g. with dx=dy=...=0.01 steps etc.